# STM32F7 discovery USB device CDC using CubeMX

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32cubemx

The thing I want to do is sending some bytes with STM32F7 discovery to my laptop, through [USB CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) (HS or FS). I tested the virtual com example provided by keil microvision so the hardware is OK, but I need to do it using STM32CubeMX. The libraries are different and the best luck I had, was seeing Virtual Com Port in device manager. but Hyperterminal or Putty cannot detect it and there is no sending or receiving data. I have attached my sample code link and clock config, so I appreciate if anyone could help and tell me what the problem is.

[My Sample Code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw_1xnMHJ4qkblhBWGhTaDJIR2s)

[image: Clock Config]

Comment: This isn't a problem that can be easily solved on sites like e.se. I've done a lot of STM32 USB work, and CubeMX has VCP examples you can probably leverage to get yours to work. It is a bit of a tedious process and may take you down into the seedy underbelly of low level USB operation.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555364/3820025

Make sure to install the STM32 VCP driver correctly (read the comments as well under the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. The problem was related to the heap size. I increased the heap size in the startup file from 200 bytes to 400 bytes, so it's working like a charm. But still not the whole problem has been solved. when I use Keil rtx, it stops working. The previous  problem appears again. I believe it is about the stack size in rtx config, but with some changes, it's still not working.

Edited:
After a lot of challenge it worked out. In [this](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/STM32Cube/General/html/cubemx__r_t_x.html) link, it describes some tips about using RTOS-RTX with Stm32CubeMX. One of the things you need to do is setting the priority of SysTick timer in the lowest value. This conflicts with USB interrupts. To use USB-CDC with RTOS-RTX in Stm32CubeMX, you have to set the priority of USB-OTG global interrupt, lower than the SysTick timer. So setting SysTick priority to 14 and USB-OTG to 15 solves the problem.